# Set the background to a default image if there isn't a specified "featured image"

Tags: php, functions, post-thumbnails, images

I am having a little trouble displaying a default image as a background image when a feature image is not present. This is the code I am using

```
 <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
 <?php $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array( 5600,1000 ), false, '' );?>
 <?php else :
 $src = get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory') . '/lib/images/home1-1024x681.jpg'; ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
 <section id="halfpro" style="background:url(<?php echo $src[0]; ?> ) no-repeat center center">
```

When I upload a feature image it works but when I do not have one selected the div is empty. When I look at the source it seems as though it is not rendering the URL correctly, I am getting this background:url(h ).

What am I missing?

Comment: Your certain `$src = get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory') . '/lib/images/home1-1024x681.jpg';` returns an image? That the `home1-1024x681.jpg` image actually exists in your `wp-content/themes/your-theme/lib/images/` directory? Try using `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` or `get_bloginfo('template_directory')` instead of `get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory') `.

Comment: I am 100% sure. I tried each solutions you provided and still nothing. The problem seems to be it is not displaying the url in the source. All I am getting now is background:url(h )@BODA82

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution from a Wordpress forum and this is what they used. Works perfect

```
 <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
 <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), '' );
 $image = $image[0]; ?>
 <?php else :
 $image = get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/lib/images/home1-1024x681.jpg'; ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
 <section id="halfpro" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image; ?>')" >
```